# What is the mainframe in this image in Ireland?

Tags: mainframe, identify-this-computer

Someone recently posted this image of his gran (on the right).

[image]
Mainframes were before my era, can anyone positively identify the model? I don't see a console in the image, which is where I would normally look. Taken in Ireland, unsure of the date.

There appear to be logos on the tape drives at the back, the rectangles with silver on either side? One comment suggests they say IBM, but  I can't make them out and I don't recall it ever looking like that. Given it's in Ireland, perhaps one of ICL's predecessors?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an ICL machine, likely 1900.  1900s (all except one) use a modified KSR33 teletype as the console, which is what the man in the centre of the photo is sitting at.  Those rectangular buttons on peripherals were used on 1900s, as well.

Comment: I was discounting ICL because I thought they formed later for some reason, and thus though it might be EE or ICT. But yeah, this appears to be from some time after 1965 and thus ICL it is.

Comment: Oh, I don't really distinguish the ICT 1900 from the ICL 1900.

Comment: The devices of which one is behind the operators head (or in front of it, from his viewpoint) and the other behind the woman seated and overseeing the printer, look like [1916 paper tape readers](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ict_icl/1900/brochures/1916_Paper_Tape_Reader_Sep64.pdf),  Once again, the thing that seems to be missing is the computer.

Comment: Judging by the chair and the hairstyles I would guess the timeframe is roughly 1960-1966.

Comment: The right-hand printer seems to require close supervision.

Comment: Trick question: I don't think there's a computer in the picture. I see a lot of printers, tape drives, card readers and maybe disks, but not an actual computer.

Comment: And mainframes are not "before your era". They are still very much alive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks to me like an [ICT 1902](https://collection.fletcherarchives.co.nz/objects/59499/fletcher-holdings-ltd-computer-bureau-1966-ict-series-1902-computer-l-r-line-printer-four-magnetic-tape-units-card-reader-in-foreground-console-typewriter-which-controls-the-whole-system).

The printer here looks the same, same vents etc.

[image]

According to [this list](https://techarchives.irish/irelands-first-computers-1956-69/) the picture is probably either at Player Wills Ltd or the Guinness brewery.

Comment: The tape decks don't look the same, though.  I'm familiar with the ones in your photo here, but not the ones in the OP's photo. Maybe older models, or 7-track versus 9-track?

Comment: The tape decks in your photo are 1971, 1972, or [1973 decks](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ict_icl/1900/brochures/1973_Magnetic_Tape_System_Sep64.pdf), which look similar but have different capabilities.  The decks in the OP's photo are [1974 decks](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/ict_icl/1900/brochures/1974_Magnetic_Tape_System_Sep64.pdf).  Those are model numbers, not  years!  Per bitsavers, the pictures are all from 1964 (year, not model number).

Comment: One thing that's not in your photo is... a computer !